# Change border style of button

Tags: html, css

here you can search button background is in circle shape as  [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/paris-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

[image]

but i want to make it rectangular shape as [link2](http://stylebaby.com/testproduct.html) :

[image]

```
background: #ff7704 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;
```

Comment: remove border-radius:10px or add border-radius:0px with this css.

Comment: @Leothelion post your comment s answer

Comment: add ur css ` border-radius:0;`

Comment: @user9999 please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for your point is try to add id or class to that button and then add `border-radius:0px` to that particular button so your button will be square and it won't affect other buttons too. Thank you

Comment: thnaks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first link, there is the following CSS code:

```
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5px;
    min-width: 140px;
    float: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Remove the `border-radius: 10px;` or overwrite it by using `border-radius: 0`, and you got a rectangle button.

Comment: thnaks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Add Your button  css for the
(Really its working,)

**example**

```
.btn{
        border-radius:0;
    }
```

### **try this**

```
border-radius:0;
```

Comment: `.btn ` just example, I know that path, he is not given any class file name, think about it

Comment: thnaks for support.

Comment: what is our answer,

Answer (score 0):

border-radius to 0px will make it rectangle. Please find the css style below

```
.button{
 min-height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 0px 30px;
 float: left;
 min-width: 160px;
 width: 100%;
 white-space: normal;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thnaks for support.

Comment: as other user commented first and gave the hint , i accepted his answer.